# How can i make stripe lines in between geometric stripes with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i wanted to ask if there is an efficient way (any mathematic algorithm, built-in function) to put vertical "strips" between let's say an oval. Here is a exemple code where i'd like to put strips

```
from tkinter import *  


painting = Canvas(root, width = 120, height = 160).pack()
painting.create_oval(35,70,85,90, outline = "red",width =3)
```

[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsRpa.png)

[image: Visual example]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom fill pattern by creating your own .xbm bitmap file (see [1](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/bitmaps.html)) and pass it to the `stipple` option (see [2](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_oval.html)).

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.pack()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.painting = tk.Canvas(self, width=120, height=160)
        self.painting.create_oval(35, 70, 85, 90, outline="red", width=3, stipple='@/tmp/stripes.xbm', fill='red')
        self.painting.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Content of `/tmp/stripes.xbm`:

```
#define stripes_width 8
#define stripes_height 1
static unsigned char stripes_bits[] = {
   0x07 };
```

`0x07` = `00000111` is the binary representation of the 8 pixels. The color is specified by the `fill` option.

Result:

[image]